# load more data from table using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 7 data in my database

I try to load my data from table using `ajax` and `php`.

but after I click the button load more the data is showing but `load more` button is gone.

here my index.php code https://github.com/jazuly1/piratefiles/blob/master/index.php

here my ajax code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'getData.php',
            data:'idpost='+ID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.tutorial_list').append(html);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

and my getdata.php code https://github.com/jazuly1/piratefiles/blob/master/getdata.php

before I click load more button

[image]

after I click load more button. the button is gone.

[image]

Comment: `$('.show_more').hide();` and `$('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();` seem you hide and remove!

Comment: Instead of $('.show_more').hide(); try; $('.show_more').fadeOut().delay(6000).fadeIn(); Hope this will work. After 6 seconds "show more" will show again. Also you can remove this line from success ... $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();

Comment: i try u code but it load same post....

Comment: https://github.com/jazuly1/piratefiles/blob/master/getdata.php#L14 you have SQL Injection vulnerabilities in this code.  You don't sanitize your _POST data before inserting it, unescaped, into an SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

When "Show More" is clicked, you `$('.show_more').hide()` which makes sense.  But you never show it again?  You also completely remove a similar selection (`$('#show_more_main'+ID).remove()`) but as far as I can tell, that doesn't have any effect.

Change the `remove()` to something like:

```
$('.show_more').show();
$('.loding').hide();
```

Comment: What is your strategy for updating your "Show more" URL? do you want to _replace_ the existing "show more" with a new one, or _update_ the "show more"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have removed the `Load more` section with `jQuery` and expecting it from the `getData` API call. But the `getData` API call returns html with `<tr>...</tr>`'s content and in addition `Show more` section, if needed. It is better to either use `JSON` response and generate those `<tr>...</tr>`'s manually in Java Script, or a `JSON` response with two sections, may be in below format:

```
{
    'content': '<tr><td>...</td></tr>....<tr><td>...</td></tr>',
    'showMore': '<div class="show_more_main" ...</div>'
}
```

Than from the response (do not forget to use `response = $.parseJSON(response)`) read the `content` and append as `$('.tutorial_list').append(response.content)` for data section and similarly `$("table.table").append(response.showMore)` for show more section.

I believe you got the idea, where you are doing wrong.

But if you still want to use your own code instead of `JSON`, just use the below trick.

Step 1: In `getdata.php` update show more section with below code (Keeping the `Show more` section invisible):

```
<?php endforeach;
    if($data > $showLimit){ ?>
        <div class="show_more_main" style="visibility:hidden" id="show_more_main<?php echo $tutorial_id; ?>">
            <span id="<?php echo $tutorial_id; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts" href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Show more</span>
            <span class="loding" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw" style="font-size:12px;"></i>Loading....</span></span>
        </div>
    <?php }   
    } 
}?>
```

Step 2: Move the hidden section `Show more` to the right place using `Java Script` in `index.php`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'getData.php',
            data:'idpost='+ID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.tutorial_list').append(html);
                //Move to new right place if show more section exists. You may give data table an id if you want
                $(".show_more_main").appendTo("table.table");
                $(".show_more_main").show();
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps you. Feel free to write comment, if any part is not clear to you.